# SQL select Group by with max

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, inner-join

```
Create Table table_name(p_id VARCHAR(50), d_id VARCHAR(50), t_id VARCHAR(50), version INT, source VARCHAR(50), name VARCHAR(50), county VARCHAR(50));
        
Insert Into table_name Values('p1','d1','t1',2,'online','penny','usa'),
        ('p1','d1','t1',2,'manual','penny','india'),
        ('p1','d1','t1',1,'online','penny','india'),
        ('p1','d1','t1',1,'manual','penny','usa'),
        ('p2','d2','t2',4,'online','david','india'),
        ('p2','d2','t2',4,'online','david','usa'),
        ('p2','d2','t2',1,'online','david','usa'),
        ('p2','d2','t2',1,'manual','david','india'),
        ('P3','d3','d3',3,'online','raj','india');
    
select * from table
    where (p_id, d_id, t_id, version)
    in (
        select p_id, d_id, t_id, version from table
            where (p_id, d_id, t_id, version)
                in ( select p_id, d_id, t_id, max(version) from table group by p_id, d_id, t_id ) //1. fetch distinct of (p_id, d_id, t_id) and with max(version)
        group by p_id, d_id, t_id, version
        having count(*)>1   //2. get only records which has both source = online and source = manual. note-- we should ignore p3 because it doesn't have both online and manual'
        );
```

**output**: for each unique values of(p_id, d_id, t_id) we should get two records with max version available

```
results: p2-d2-t2 with version 4

p1-d1-t1  and p3-d3-t3 should be ignored because it has only one value.
```

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data!!

Comment: Post data as formatted text - here is a tool to help https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables and/or provide SQL to create and populate tables.

Comment: @June7 There should be a [mre] so the table should be initialization code formatted in columns. Also for other tables there is now a format in the post editor described in the edit help.

Comment: @philipxy, that's nice but TablesGenerator saves a lot of typing. Can copy/paste from db into the tool.

Comment: @June7 The code they ran should be in the post. Not non-code that generates code that may or may not be the code they ran. I'm done.

Comment: Is there a typo error for p3-d3-d3 record - should that be p3-d3-t3?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the max and count window functions as the following:

```
Select p_id, d_id, t_id, version, source, name, county  
From
(
  Select *,
    Max(version) Over (Partition By p_id, d_id, t_id) max_ver,
    Count(*) Over (Partition By p_id, d_id, t_id, version) cnt
  From table_name
) T
Where version = max_ver And cnt = 2
Order By p_id, d_id, t_id
```

Another option, you could use aggregation as the following:

```
Select p_id, d_id, t_id, version, source, name, county
From table_name T
Where (p_id, d_id, t_id, version) In
(
  Select p_id, d_id, t_id, Max(version)
  From table_name
  Group By p_id, d_id, t_id
)
And 
(
  Select Count(*) H From table_name D 
  Where 
  D.p_id=T.p_id And D.d_id=T.d_id And D.t_id=T.t_id And D.version=T.version
) = 2 
Order By p_id, d_id, t_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RToYu4Te).

Comment: Thank you. @Ahmed!
I have verified the solution but it stll giving results when it has one record. We need two records with every max version. If more than two or less than two then ignore it.

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the answer according to this, check and let me know if it's OK.

Comment: @MaruthiS, should include that info in your question narrative. It definitely helps in understanding.

Comment: @ahmed, I see same results in fiddle.

Comment: @June7, what do you mean by the same results?

Comment: Same output as before this latest edit.

Comment: Yes, it should be the same, according to the input data.

Comment: According to OP's comment *I have verified the solution but it stll giving results when it has one record*, I think he tested the previous query on his real data.

Comment: Your sample data is not quite what the OP posted and I think OP has an error in their sample. I fixed the data in the fiddle and the output is correct.

Comment: I used the sample data he posted at the first time, I think it's the same check this https://dbfiddle.uk/RToYu4Te

Comment: Same output. Now look at my fix of data: https://dbfiddle.uk/qbpS3L8W. Your code works.

Comment: I think you missed the first row `('p1','d1','t1',2,'online','penny','usa')`

Comment: That line has a 1 in the current posted data. The posting has an error in p3-d3-d3 as well.

Comment: I refreshed the page many times, still gives me that row!! Actually, the OP posted the sample data as an image, I converted it to DDL, DML then he used this DDL, DML in his post.

Comment: OP said only p2-d2-t2 should be returned. Changing that value to a 2 does mess this up.

Comment: Oooh, my fault, I misunderstood the expected output, I thought he wants p2-d2-t2 and p1-d1-t1, thank you so much for this clarification.

Comment: No, wait. I could be wrong. I looked at older version of question and now it looks like they do want both of those records. The current question narrative is not so clear. In which case their data sample is botched.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just noticed that. So I will wait for his response. According to the provided logic in his comments, the row p1-d1-t1,2 should be returned